# Why is the tool tip text centered when hovering over a question on Stack Overflow's start page?

Tags: discussion

Just wondering if there's any reason to have the tool tip text centered as opposed to left justified on the home page of Stack Overflow as you hover over a question. It seems like it might make it easier to read. Also, this looks like the kind of things you guys discussed a lot about already, so excuse me if I'm late to this.

I am seeing this on an Ubuntu Trusty machine using Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153

UPDATE: I just checked on firefox, and things are left justtified. I still don't know why it looks weird on my chrome, but it's clearly a browser issue and not a meta discussion. Thanks guys!

This is what I'm talking about:
[image: Screenshot of the tooltip]

Comment: Um. What tooltip, exactly?

Comment: @Oded sorry, that was confusing. I hope it's clear now, I also included the screenshot

Comment: OK. Now, what browser and OS are you on?

Comment: @Oded just added, Ubuntu Trusty machine using Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153

Comment: looks like an Ubuntu quirk then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an OS or browser quirk. It's a system tooltip (generated by the `title` HTML attribute on the respective `<a>` element), which is controlled by the system theme for the most part and not by any of Stack Overflow's CSS (in fact, it's not possible to style a system tooltip with CSS).

Comment: Quite right. This is just the contents of the "title" attribute of the question link - how it is rendered is entirely dependent on the browser and the OS.

Comment: I agree. I just checked on firefox, and things are left justtified. I still don't know why it looks weird on my chrome, but it's clearly a browser issue and not a meta discussion. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Oded so, dug more into it, there's a [Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348183)  on this, and indeed it's chrome specific